# Foolproof way to strip whitespace from a Ruby variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whitespace, strip

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.2.7.  I'm having trouble stripping off white space from a variable. I can't tell what kind of white space it is. Is there a foolproof strip method?  When I cut and paste from a certain variable I’m unable to strip the white space but, when I type the space, then everything is okay. See my console below:

```
2.3.0 :004 >   test = " 21"
 => " 21" 
2.3.0 :005 > test.strip
 => " 21"
```

I have cut and paste from another source and the white space isn’t being stripped off.  Is there a way I can have some kind of foolproof strip method for my variables?

Comment: Are you able to provide the source or an example from it?

Comment: Not replicating your fault when I try, so whatever kind of space character is in there has not been copied to your question. Could you add the results of `test.bytes` and `test.encoding` to the question?

Comment: The "space" is a non-breaking space, AKA `"\xa021"`.

Comment: When asking about invisible characters it's important to provide a way for people to easily replicate the problem. We _can_ edit the question and select the text from there but that's tribal knowledge and a lot of people don't think of that. Instead, provide a string assignment that will recreate the actual string. This is all part of creating a question that fits "[mcve]".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have a non-ASCII Unicode whitespace character, most likely 0x00A0:

```
> test = "\u00A021"
 => " 21" 
> test.strip
 => " 21"
```

and [`String#strip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-strip) only (currently) knows about ASCII whitespace:

> **strip → new_str**
>   [...]
>
> Whitespace is defined as any of the following characters: null, horizontal tab, line feed, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space.

You can do it by hand with [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) and the [`Space` character property](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties):

```
> test = "\u00A0 21 \t\u00a0"
 => "  21 \t " 
> test.gsub(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '')
 => "21"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the normal `\s` or `\S` to handle extended characters in UTF-8 or Unicode. Instead I'd do something like this:

```
" 21".gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, '') # => "21"
```

or maybe:

```
" 21".gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, '')
```

See "[Character Classes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes)" in the Regexp documentation.

You can figure out what a character is by using `ord.to_s(16)` on it:

```
>> test = " 21"
" 21"
>> test.ord
160
>> test.ord.to_s(16)
"a0"
>> test[0].ord.to_s(16)
"a0"
```

Or by looking at it in an editor that can show the actual ordinal value, such as Vim.

Answer (score -2):

Try with a regexp

```
test.gsub(/\A\s*(\S(.*\S)?)?\s*\z/,'\1')
```

The weird (\S(.*\S)?)? part at the middle catches the text between \A\s* <- white spaces at the beginning and \s*\z <- white spaces at the end

Comment: But `\s` is still only ASCII-aware and `String#strip` will take care of any ASCII whitespace.

Comment: `\s` and `\S` are not sufficient to catch unicode characters. They're defined in http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes